What transistor should I use to make a replica of the 555 Timer IC
My professor told me to make a 555 timer IC using transistors. Someone suggested to use BC307 for the PNP transistor used, and BC377 for the NPN transistor used, but I can't get my hands on the BC377 transistor, so I was looking for an alternative. Can I use BC337 instead? Is there any other type of NPN transistor that works?


farid - Hi, Where did the image come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online & public, please [edit] the question & add the webpage/PDF name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + its URL). If the source is offline (e.g. printed book or private intranet) then [edit] the question & add full source details e.g. title, author, page, publisher, edition. TY (More rules in the [tour] & [help].)

I'm wondering what course you are taking for your prof to suggest building a 555 from scratch. https://www.instructables.com/Build-Your-Own-555-Timer/

Consider the differences between the BC377 and the BC337. Look at their datasheets and determine if there are different applications and whether their differences are significant enough to allow them to be interchangeable. This exercise will help you be a better engineer  after you graduate. Making these sort of decisions will appear plenty of times during your career so it would be good to learn this as soon as possible.

i took the image from this website , and checked a few others to make sure it's correct : https://howtomechatronics.com/how-it-works/555-timer-ic-working-principle-block-diagram-circuit-schematics/
i did check the data sheet as you said , i think it should be fine .
thank you for answers :D

@farid - Hi, You said: "i took the image from this website {...} https://howtomechatronics.com/how-it-works/555-timer-ic-working-principle-block-diagram-circuit-schematics/" That statement seems to be false. The image you copied into the question above, does not appear on that webpage.

Just about any small signal NPN and PNP transistors will work.  I like the 2N4401/4403, but other options are 2N3904/3906 and 2N2222/2219.

Don’t you need matched transistors for the comparator inputs and current mirrors?

Not to achieve basic functionality.  The comparators might have a bit higher input offset voltage error, and the current mirrors won't be perfectly balanced, but that's true of any discrete build of an analog IC.  The comparators will compare and the latch will latch, even if you use something like a 2N3055 for the NPN parts.

I was always taught that you need to be extremely careful about building any analog IC internal schematic from discrete parts (like you said) due to mismatches in the discrete parts.  For example, a measly 20mV VBE mismatch for these transistors results in a huge error in the current output.  You can remedy most of it by using "resistor ballasting" in the emitters, but it results in lower compliance voltage as a tradeoff.  Is your answer inferring that for this particular IC, it's much less of a risk due to its specific construction/building-blocks?

If you are talking about replicating an IC's performance to its spec, then yes, very fine matching is required.  But to poke around in a relatively simple and imprecise part like a 555 just to see how its innards work, I think you can get there with unmatched transistors.  The story is that Hans did exactly that on his kitchen table.

Awesome.  Thanks!

thank you  for your answer :D !

Glad I could help.
